# assert afxcurrentinstancehandle null calling MFC dll from exe

Tags: visual-studio-2008, visual-c++, mfc, visual-studio-debugging, vtk

I have a MFC app where I am calling a mfc dll (vtkMFC.dll) from the exe. There I am getting a debug assertion as below in afxwin1.inl.

> { ASSERT(afxCurrentInstanceHandle != NULL);

I tried to use `AfxSetResourceHandle(GetModuleHandle("vtkMFC.dll"))` but still getting the same error.
I am using `"use MFC in a static library"` option.
Below is my code:

> ```
>     AFX_MANAGE_STATE(AfxGetStaticModuleState())
>     CWaitCursor WC; // sometimes takes a while to start
>     CCCADApp *app = (CCCADApp *)AfxGetApp();
>     CFrameWnd *frame = app->pVtkTemplate->CreateNewFrame( this, NULL );
>     // first init creates the view 
>     app->pVtkTemplate->InitialUpdateFrame( frame, this, FALSE);
>     CvtkMDIView* view= dynamic_cast<CvtkMDIView*>(frame->GetActiveView()); 
>     //
>     // automatic correction - try to load initial field if solution is not available
>     if(run->GetStatus()==CDawesRun::NOTRUN) options=VTKInitialField|VTKGrid|(options & VTKView2D);
>     if(view) view->setData(run,options,variable); // set data
>     // show the view and frame
>     app->pVtkTemplate->InitialUpdateFrame( frame, this, TRUE);
> ```

My main app is built with, "Multi-threaded Debug (/MTd)" option where the dll is built with, Multi-threaded Debug DLL (/MDd).
Does it have something to do with this?
Please help me.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem.  I fixed it by adding a call:

```
AfxWinInit(::GetModuleHandle(NULL), NULL, ::GetCommandLine(), 0))
```

before I started calling MFC functions and objects (like CWaitCursor).  This function is usually called in WinMain().

Answer (score 0):

Why do you link statically against MFC/CRT?  I'm not sure about MFC, but I believe linking against the CRT statically/dynamically in different modules of the application is not supported.

Can you try and build with /MDd, *and* link dynamically to MFC, and say if it helps?

Comment: Thanks a lot for the reply Ofek. My main project is statically linked. So I could not change it. My third party lib and dll (vtk) files were dynamically linked. Changing them also did not solve the problem, hence I used the file giving the error (vtkMFCWindow) directly in the main app and removed its __declspec(dllexport) definitions. Now it is working fine. Thanks again.